# Is there a way to pass values to SFDX force:apex:execute

Tags: salesforcedx

I am trying to trigger Apex code from CircleCI but I want to pass a value to my code. Reading through the documentation for `force:apex:execute` I don't see an option to pass any values to my apex code. It seems that I can only trigger the code.

So I can do `$ sfdx force:apex:execute -u testusername@salesforce.org -f ~/test.apex` but my I need my code to receive a value to act on.

Would there be a different way that I can use to pass some values to my apex code?

**EDIT** I guess I could possibly use `sfdx data:record:create` to create a record in salesforce and then have my apex code reference that to pull the value it needs. This is a pretty dirty option so I am looking for other solutions.

Comment: You have to include the parameters in the code itself.

Comment: @PhilW In my case my parameter is dynamic. That's my issue.

Comment: @PhilW I updated my question. I can store the value in a record in Salesforce but that doesn't seem optimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pipe a string in, so build that string however you like.

This is from our GitHub Actions CI where it is just a fixed string of Apex code:

```
run: echo "new DefaultCallable().call('xxx', null);" | sfdx force:apex:execute
```

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: This is including the parameter in the code itself; you just happen to have the code inline in the script.

Comment: I don't have code for it off hand, but the way I've done this is to have placeholders in the .apex file and use sed to replace them with the dynamic value prior to calling the command from within a shell script: Shell script accepts args, then sed replacement in the .apex file, then sfdx apex run -f. Not great, but works.